# Concat values recovered from the form and send email to this values in c#

Tags: c#

I have problems with this string in C# asp net 4.

I need concat the values recovered from the form and send email to this values.

I tried this but I have error:

```
An invalid character was found in the mail header: ','.
```

What am I missing?

What's wrong with this code?

Thank you in advance.

My code below:

```
all = string.Concat(Request.Form["a"] + "," + Request.Form["b"]);
commaSeparated = string.Join(", ", all.ToString());

Response.Write(commaSeparated);

mailMessagePlainText.To.Add(new MailAddress(commaSeparated.ToString()));
```

Comment: What's the value of `commaSeparated`?

Comment: shouldnt be that a semicolon rather than a comma?

Comment: a@a.com,b@a.com,c@a.com,d@a.com,e@a.com,f@a.com

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger: No. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/MailAddressParser.cs,51

Comment: @SLaks yeah you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As its name implies, a `MailAddress` can only hold a single address.

Call [`To.Add(commaSeparated)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/MailAddressCollection.cs,20) to add multiple addresses.